# How to avoid "orphaned" paragraph breaks in Scrivener?

Tags: kindle, formatting

I am using Scrivener to edit my book and publish it to Kindle. Right now, when a paragraph flows past the end of the page, sometimes only one line of this paragraph is shown on the next paragraph. Does anybody know if it's possible to avoid this with special formatting?

What I'm talking about is something like this (the "selves" word on the page at right):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a consequence of ebooks being reflowable; to all practical purposes, it's unavoidable, and it has nothing to do with Scrivener. There is theoretically CSS support for eliminating both widows (like what you've shown) and orphans (the reverse, where there's a single line at the bottom of the page), but the majority of ebook reading systems do not support them.

If you'd like to give it a shot anyway, you'll have to edit the CSS file and add:

```
widows: 2
orphans: 2
```

The `2` represents the minimum number of new lines that should be left at the top/bottom of a page.